# Collision detection by color in car game

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to create a car game in C# with XNA.

I have a picture, the track, as the background. The track is painted black, so I need to check when the car is outside the black color, then I know its outside the track.

I don't really know how to start. I checked some websites and a method called `GetPixel` was described but it was slow. I think I need this code to run a few times per second so it has to be quick . I also found `LockBits` which i think may work.

Is this the right way to go? Could someone help me understand `LockBits`?

Comment: There's not enough information at all in your question for anyone to help you. We don't even know if you're coding in `C` or `C#`, what framework you're using, how you're representing a car and the ground...

Comment: Texture that has a black color!!!

Comment: Add more (appropriate) tags to your question and clarify it more, are you using XNA for example?

Comment: eh, someone changed my title.. its C SHARP! and im using XNA!

Comment: Use tags to tag questions, not titles.

Comment: @user1112727: now please describe what you have tried so far to do this detection, or at least how you represent cars and ground tiles, and your question could be re-opened. (Do that by editing your question, not adding more comments.)

Comment: It's a bad idea to have graphics influence game behavior.

Comment: While `Graphics.GetPixel` is slow, that doesn't mean "few times per second" is a problem. `GetPixel` is often slow if you want to get all pixels in a larger bitmap, but only because a bitmap typically has a million pixels or so. But I'm not sure if `System.Drawing` is available on XNA.

Comment: I edited it and hopefully asked it correct this time!

Comment: I edited the previous question but it was still closed, so i thought i had to create a new one with the extra details... I will keep that in mind anyhow! Can you help me?

Comment: Once you've edited the question enough for it to be clear and answerable, it can be reopened by a vote, same as closing. Your other question currently has a few votes to reopen, but could use a bit more description (in particular, what you've tried or what you think might work, some indication of effort, is a good thing to include). Nocturn's answer, below, is a very good idea and one of the better solutions (certainly the fastest).

Comment: I think you'r correct. System.Drawing is not available on xna. What should I do?

Comment: In addition to what @peachykeen said, if your question isn't getting enough reopen votes, you can flag it so a moderator will reopen it instantly for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [stencil buffer with an occlusion query](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/12/31/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-using-gpu-occlusion-queries.aspx) This will give you only if there was a collision or not. If you need detailed information about where the collision happened, it's probably better to do it on the CPU instead of the GPU. If you need an algorithm for that let me know and I'll update this answer.